# how to change binding of a property name in java binding library

Tags: android, xamarin, java-binding

I have this Java code, with CaptureApiError property in SignInResultHandlerSignInError:

```
[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/janrain/android/Jump", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)] public partial class Jump : global::Java.Lang.Object {

          [global::Android.Runtime.Register("com/janrain/android/Jump$SignInResultHandler$SignInError", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
          public partial class SignInResultHandlerSignInError : global::Java.Lang.Object {

                  static IntPtr captureApiError_jfieldId;

                  [Register ("captureApiError")]
                  public global::Com.Janrain.Android.Capture.CaptureApiError CaptureApiError {  get { ... } set { ... } }
```

How to change the name of the property to something else?

This is what I tried to put in Metadata.xml:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.janrain.android']/class[@name='Jump.SignInResultHandlerSignInError']/property[@name='CaptureApiError']" name="managedName">CaptureApiError1</attr>
```

I am not sure if the xpath

> /property[@name='']"

is valid for MetaData.xml.

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163864/rename-interface-property-in-metadata I see you're still waiting for an answer!